# Cron : Execute job based first N days of month only

Tags: spring, cron

I have implemented one scheduler job which is required to execute only for first N days. Is it possible to make any particular cron expression to achieve this functionality?

Normally, I am using **http://www.cronmaker.com/**. However, It looks like, the tool is not supported for this kind of cron expression.

Can anyone please provide your thoughts?

Comment: The site you have mentioned generates 7 digit cron expressions...Spring only have 6 digit cron expressions check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: Also what is mean by only first N days..can you post a sample example..

Comment: @Sangam Belose: Correct. However, we can ignore the last one position of cron from cronmaker.com and it would work fine for spring framework.

Comment: @Sangam Belose: I would like to have kind of cron expression which would trigger the job only for first 5 days of every month. Like, 1-5th date of every month.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 17 1-5 1/1 ? ")
```

This cron expression will execute on every month 1 to 5 days at 5 PM. ( you can specify what time you want to run that job on that day.)

below is the sample spring boot class by which you can verify the solution.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 17 1-5 1/1 ? ")
    public void sampleScheduled() {

        System.out.println("Just testing the scheduler");
    }
}
```